# How to disable jQuery properties in media query css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to remove or disable jQuery properties (Class and Id) in media query css? I want to remove or disable the properties if it reaches to 991px size.

Here's my code.

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
            $('#stickyHeader').addClass("sticky01");
            $('.site-title').attr("id", "stSize");        
            $('#site-navigation').addClass("stNavSize");        
        }else{
            $('#stickyHeader').removeClass("sticky01");
            $('.site-title').removeAttr("id", "stSize");
            $('#site-navigation').removeClass("stNavSize");
            $('.site-title').addClass("stSize2");
            $('#site-navigation').addClass("stNavSize2");
        }
    });
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: _"I want to remove or disable the properties if it reaches to 991px size"_ What is "it"? Do you mean `window.innerWidth`?

Comment: What is a "jQuery property"?

Comment: Nope. What I want to achieve is that when the browser is in 991px width all my jQuery properties will be disable

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new class or id with 991px and set it's display=none,

@media you can addClass for screen larger than 991px

I hope it helps, otherwise write me in comment and I will be glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

CSS media queries to change elements at some viewport breakpoint

```
/* CSS for > 991px */

.element {
  color: red;
}

/* CSS for < 991px */

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .element {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

jQuery to add/remove classes, id's etc, on `load` and `resize`

```
$(window).on('load resize',function() {
 if ($(this).width() > 991) {
     $('#stickyHeader').addClass("sticky01");
 } else {
      $('#stickyHeader').removeClass("sticky01");
 }
});
```

Comment: Hello,

I want to remove all of these in 991px:

sticky01,
stSize,
stNavSize,
stSize2,
stNavSize2

Comment: "remove all of these" what do you mean? be more specific please.

Comment: Opps. I apologize. What i want to achieve is that when it reaches to 991px all the class and id that I made in jquery will be disable to stop the events from continuing

Comment: @MelvinRey then either use the media query example I gave to override the styles with whatever you wanted to do, or use jQuery to remove the classes/ID's that you applied.

Comment: `991px` is not a number.